# pdfmake with Typescript/In StencilJS Project

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs, pdfmake

I am using pdf maker in my StencilJs app using the official Documentation at https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/client-side/
First of all, I have installed it via npm using:

```
npm install pdfmake
```

Then I have created the following to test the functionality:

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';


(<any>pdfMake).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs; 

export class PDFCreateService {


  constructor() {
 // empty
 }


public createNachrichtPDF(message: string): any {
 const fileName: string = 'ba-postfach-' + moment(new Date()).format('DD-MM-YYYY');

  const docDefinition = {
    content: [message]
  };


  return pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
}
```

}

This code does not work and in the class My-Messages where I instantiate this class, I keep on getting the following error:

```
index-2022e853.js:2706 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined 
(reading 'pdfMake') at my-messages.entry.js:78239 undefined

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Constructor for "my-messages#undefined" was 
not found at initializeComponent
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: It looks like `vfs_fonts.js` export the `vfs` object only so maybe this would work: `pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts;`

Comment: It still does not work :(

Comment: Stencil uses Typescript, so your reference should look like this: 
import * as pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';

(<any>pdfMake).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

Comment: Have tried your suggesion, makes no differrence

Comment: @user1107888 same error?

Comment: Unfortunately yes